# fast access to objects through a many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I am wondering how I can speed up my web application. I have a table which has 1.5 million entries. About 10 columns in that table are only used by about 600 000 objects. So I thought it would be a good idea to create a new table with these 10 columns and include a relationship between the first table and the new one. To account for some special cases I made it a many to many relationship. I use sqlalchemy with a postgres database and I basically followed the documentation

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many

Everything works find, but getting the objects from the new table is very slow. I am wondering why? There should be a way to index such a relation and access to related objects very quickly?

My setup is given below. As soon as I have a paper object I access the related doi records with

```
paper.doi_records
```

The access to a column in the papers table takes about 10^-5 seconds, while the access to the doi_record in the new table takes about 10^-2 seconds...

Here is my setup

```
class Paper(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(1000), primary_key=True, index=True)
    doi = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    ...
def __repr__(self):
    return '<Paper %r>' % (self.id)

class DOI_record(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'doi_record'
    doi = db.Column(db.String(1000), primary_key=True, index=True)       
    ...

    papers = db.relationship('Paper', secondary=related_dois, backref=db.backref('doi_records'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<DOI_record %r>' % (self.doi)

related_dois = db.Table('related_dois',
    db.Column('paper_id', db.String(1000), db.ForeignKey('paper.id')),
    db.Column('doi', db.String(1000), db.ForeignKey('doi_record.doi'))
)
```

Comment: We'd have to see your table definitions to confirm indexes are in place, but many-to-many relationships are notoriously slow in RDBMS and breaking your table into 3 just to save on 10 columns does seem like it'd be a good approach to optimize performance. Column loading is incredibly efficient in an RDBMS compared to a join.

Comment: @TheArchitect isn't my entire table definition already above? What did I miss? Interesting that you say its not worth splitting the table... part of my question was certainly whether this all is a good idea...?

Comment: I meant the actual database definition from your database, e.g. MySQL desc or Psql \d. SQLAlchemy is only a view on it and there might be discrepancies... Introducing many-to-many joins to split a table is unlikely to be a net performance benefit imho again.

Comment: yes I can see that a join would be slow, but isn't there a way to just index this relation, so that each Paper can access all DOI_records in O(1)?

Comment: Indexes on your foreign keys would probably help, especially if you have the columns you fetch from the second table in the index, so only the index has to be read.

Comment: again we'd have to see your rdbms table definitions to really confirm that the foreign keys and indexes are in place...